# Firebase Firestore rules are preventing authenticated users from access files

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a react native project I am currently building. It used Firebase Firestore to store important information for the application including the `Profile, Favorites, Feeds, and more.` Right now I am adjusting the Firestore rules so that I can secure the firestore database.

I made changes to the rules and now that the rules are changes, I am getting `Missing or insufficient permissions` error and I dont know how to adjust the rules to work with the application once it goes life and on the Apple app store.

Here is the error:

```
 ERROR  [2023-06-26T17:59:41.457Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.21.0): 
  Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: 
  [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Here is what my rules look like right now:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /ConnectWithAgent {
      // Allow any user to write and read to the document.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /GeneralConnect {
      // Allow any user to write and read to the document.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /SellMyHome {
      // Allow any user to write and read to the document.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /ShowingTour {
      // Allow any user to write and read to the document.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /Favorites {
      // Allow any user to write to the document, but only an authenticated user can read it.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /Feed {
      // Allow any user to write to the document, but only an authenticated user can read it.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /Offers {
      // Allow any user to write to the document, but only an authenticated user can read it.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /Profiles {
      // Allow any user to write to the document, but only an authenticated user can read it.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /RecentViews {
      // Allow any user to write to the document, but only an authenticated user can read it.
      allow write: if true;
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

for the collections `ConnectWithAgent, GeneralConnect, SellMyHome, and showingTour` I want it so that anyone can read and write into those collections. For the collections `Favorites, Feed, Offers, Profiles, and RecentViews` I want it so that anyone can write into those collections but only a logged in user can read them.

I have a dev user that is logged in and when the app loads, if the user is logged in, it tried to read all of the Favorites documents that have a matching userId to the logged in users userId. That is when I get the error.

Here is that code:

```
const getFavorites = () => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Favorites')
    const q = query(collectionRef, where('userId', '==', auth.currentUser.uid))
    onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      let favoritesList = []
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        favoritesList.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
      })
      setFavorites(favoritesList)
      grabZpidList(favoritesList)
    })
  }
```

Comment: In such cases I find it helpful to log or check the `getAuth().currentUser` in this `getFavorites` function right before I call to Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing this as community wiki for other's sake.

---

As @Frank van Puffelen said:

> In such cases I find it helpful to log or check the getAuth().currentUser in this getFavorites function right before I call to Firestore.

---

Make sure that after you update your rules. Deploy them to your firestore database by using this command `firebase deploy --only firestore:rules`

Additional information that might help:

- [Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)
- [Securing data access for users and groups](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/role-based-access)